# Как подключить SSL сертификат для Tomcat на Debian

Tags: linux, http, tomcat, ssl, vps

**Дано:**

[vps](/questions/tagged/vps) на [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) с [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) и [ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl)-сертификат.

**Задача:**

Нужно подключить сертификат для возможности обращаться к приложениям, крутящимся на [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) через [https](/questions/tagged/https) с сохранением возможности ходить и по [http](/questions/tagged/http).

**Вопрос:**

Таки что нужно делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нам нужна информация о [ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl)-сертификате в виде 3 файлов:

`domain_name.crt`
`private.key`
`chain.crt`

Их можно создать вручную в текстовом редакторе и поместить в них информацию о сертификате.

Положим, что они находятся в папке `/path/to/`. Тогда мы можем получить из них файл с расширением `p12` через программу `openssl` так:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in /path/to/domain_name.crt -inkey /path/to/private.key -out mycert.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile /path/to/chain.crt -caname root -chain
```

где `mycert.p12` - собственно файл который мы должны скормить [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat)-у, а остальные - файлы сертификата. Программа предложит задать пароль, который после понадобится указать в настройках [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat)-а.

Полученный файл нужно положить в домашнюю папку юзера `tomcat`, например `/usr/share/tomcat8/`. После прописать в настройках его использование (файл `var/lib/tomcat8/conf/server.xml`):

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true"
       scheme="https" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"

       keystoreType="PKCS12"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/mycert.p12"
       keystorePass="password"
       truststoreType="PKCS12"
       truststoreFile="${user.home}/mycert.p12"
       truststorePass="password"
       />
```

Чтобы можно было ходить и по [http](/questions/tagged/http) и по [https](/questions/tagged/https) нужно также в файле `var/lib/tomcat8/conf/web.xml` в конце прописать это:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Support Both HTTP and HTTPS</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <!-- <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> -->
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

здесь важно закоментировать строку `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` или указать `NONE` вместо `CONFIDENTIAL`

Всё. Теперь можно обращаться к приложениям, крутящимся на [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) и по [http](/questions/tagged/http) и по [https](/questions/tagged/https). При этом на [https](/questions/tagged/https) надо ходить не через `8080` порт, а через `8443`.

---

Если нужен `pfx` файл, то его можно вот так сгенерировать:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out bundle.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem -password pass:password
```